# How-to make Google Search not cut off topic with an ellipsis?

Tags: google-search

I have a modern monitor from today's century, with a resolution more than 640x480 pixels. Yes seriously! =) Anyways, for some reason I have failed to understand, Google Search cut off the topic with an ellipsis like so:

[image]

It is quite annoying because most of my page with all the search results is white/blanc at the same time I am most interested in reading the full title of the page. After all, I'm searching for something right!

Any idea?

I'm also curious to know why they cut of every title like this.

Comment: as I said, my viewport is quite wide. My titles could easily fit the width without breaking into new rows. Least of all, I reason I should have the option to turn off this cutting off behavior.

Comment: They have a hard limit of 512 pixels of width ([source](http://seo-website-designer.com/Title-Length-Google-Search-Results)). So it doesn't have anything to do with the number of words or something similar.